# Fetch text till the second parenthesis in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

input:

```
str = "(samebib(A, B, 4.0) :- author(A, UniqueVar1), author(B, UniqueVar1), !)"
```

expected op:

```
str = "samebib"
```

As in I need the text between the first 2 open paranthesis.

Code Tried:

```
str.replaceAll("[\\])},].*", "")
```

Op:

```
str = "(samebib(A"
```

I am not strong in regex. Please, Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: There are several solutions to this, like: `/\((.*?)\(/`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this regex `\((.*?)\(` with pattern like this :

```
String input = "(samebib(A, B, 4.0) :- author(A, UniqueVar1), author(B, UniqueVar1), !)";
Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\(");

Matcher m = p1.matcher(input);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
samebib
```

---

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/rAF7gl/1)

---

**Note**

I used if instead of while just to take the first input, if you want to get all the inputs you can use while instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest approach would be:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\(");
System.out.println(parts[1]);
```